# How to disable Crashlytics while in debug mode, in react-native-firebase?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I have integrated firebase Crashlytics on a react native application. I want to disable crash logs while working on development mode. How can I disable crash logs in debug mode for both Android and Ios Application. To create crash logs I have followed react native firebase documentation check this official link :: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/crashlytics/android

I am using react-native-firebase version 5.2.2

I want to disable logs on debug mode without changing the version. I want to add code to disable the crash log for both Android and Ios. Please suggest how this should be done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/crashlytics/manual-initialization#1)-Disable-automatic-initialization) explains how to disable it

## iOS

Turn off automatic collection with a new key to your `Info.plist` file:

Key: `firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled`

Value: `false`

```
<key>firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled</key>
<false/>
```

## Android

Turn off automatic collection with a meta-data tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
    android:value="false" />
```

## Enable collection at runtime

You can can initialise crashlytics in your javascript code using

```
firebase.crashlytics().enableCrashlyticsCollection();
```

You can then use

```
if (__DEV__) {

} else {

}
```

to run any specific code in development or in production.

Comment: I have imported firebase , and initialized crashlytics when app is running in debug mode, but it shows me an error ::  ``_reactNativeFirebase.default.crashlytics(...).enableCrashlyticsCollection is not a function``

Comment: Did you add the values to your `Info.plist` and `AndroidManifest.xml`? As I do not get that error when I do it in my set up.

Comment: I am working on Android and added code inside AndroidManifest.xml file
`<meta-data
    android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
    android:value="false" />`

Comment: Do I need to import anything else except firebase inside my react js  file ??

Comment: I am doing nothing more than `import firebase from 'react-native-firebase'; ` then calling `if(__DEV__) { firebase.crashlytics().enableCrashlyticsCollection(); }` obviously with the edits to the `AndroidManifest.xml` and `Info.plist`.  Only thing I can think of is that you haven't put the `meta-data` in the correct place in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: I am putting `meta-data` inside the `<application ... >` section

Comment: That is really strange.

Answer (score 1):

I only need to set one line in firebase.json file,

```
{
    "react-native": {
        "crashlytics_debug_enabled": false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

faced the same in one of my project : `"react-native": "0.66.1"`

1. Edit AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.reversedomain">
     <application
       ...
       ...
      // add this line
     <meta-data
     android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
      android:value="false" />

   </application>
   ```

2. install `'@react-native-firebase/crashlytics'`
3. add .env at the root of your project & set production = false
4. in app.js

   ```
   import React from 'react'
   import { production } from '@env';
   import crashlytics from '@react-native-firebase/crashlytics';

   useEffect(()=>{
    if (production == true) {
     // Enable on runtime
    crashlytics().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
   }
   },[])
   ```
5. [docs](https://rnfirebase.io/crashlytics/usage)